# rails set datetime db column to be the same value as updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timestamp

I'm generating a document from a model, this document always needs to match the lastest version of the model, and I can't recreate it every time I load it, because it's heavy and it's sent to docusign.

I figured I could use the `updated_at` field with and additional `document_version:datetime` db column, so that the model can be updated, but when appropriate I can check if `updated_at == document_version` and know if I need to reproduce the document.

in my code I have:

```
model.update(document_version: model.updated_at)
```

this doesn't work, I'm just setting the document version to the previous value of updated_at, the `update` method changes it.

```
model.update(document_version: model.updated_at, updated_at: model.updated_at)
```

the explicit setting of updated_at seems to be ignored.

my best option would be to update the `document_version` to whatever `updated_at` is going to be updated to.

I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do this, but to strictly answer the question, this is what you can do.

```
model.update_column(:document_version, model.updated_at)
```

or updating `updated_at` directly too

```
time = Time.current
model.update_columns(document_version: time, updated_at: time)
```

[`update_column`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) does what it says, it only updates a single column without updating the `updated_at` column.

From the docs

> This is the fastest way to update attributes because it goes straight
> to the database, but take into account that in consequence the regular
> update procedures are totally bypassed. In particular:
>
> ```
> Validations are skipped.
>
> Callbacks are skipped.
>
> updated_at/updated_on are not updated.
> ```